# Consuming Laravel Passport API with javascript (React + Axios) from another application

Tags: laravel, api, reactjs, axios

I have managed to make run Laravel 5.4 and implemented the [API Authentication (Passport)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript).
[image]

What I would try to achieve is to make this as my API server and build React applications that would interact on this API.

Does this mean I have to make routes on `routes\api.php`?

Let's say I have a React app name `requestform` on development and running on `http://127.0.0.1:8080`. How will I consume an api route with axios or jquery?

I can't seem to make the correct keyword to search on google and all the samples I can get are the ones that the API and the javascript application is on the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

This post may have been answered by now. But if not then...

I think you are in the right track..

> Does this mean I have to make routes on routes\api.php?

Yes. Your API routes will depend on this file.

> Let's say I have a React app name requestform on development and running on http://127.0.0.1:8080. How will I consume an api route with axios or jquery?

Make sure your API Server is running, say it's on `http://server.dev`, you can consume the API in another app by **`http://server.dev/api/[your-routes]`**.

> I can't seem to make the correct keyword to search on google and all the samples I can get are the ones that the API and the javascript application is on the same domain.

This is a matter of what front-end programming you know. You can use any javascript knowledge to consume your own API with the same domain. There is already a Vue integration packaged in Laravel 5.4+ or just plain vanilla javascript or jQuery.